# How to listen to events from namespaced classes in Laravel 4

Tags: events, namespaces, laravel-4

Laravel 4

I'm trying to listen to events from a class in a namespace but can't work out how to set up the listener.

I have something like:

```
namespace My\Namespace
class Person  extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
...
```

In a separate class I have tried to listen for updates with

```
Event::listen('My\Namespace\Person.updated', function($person)
{
    Debugbar::info(Event::firing());
});
```

But that never gets called.  I have tried lots of different variations of upper / lower case and putting a leading \ on the namespace but nothing works

If I change the listener to

```
Event::listen('*.updated', function($person)
{
    Debugbar::info(Event::firing());
});
```

The code runs and the debug output is : eloquent.updated: My\Namespace\Person

I just need to know what name to use in place of the * to make the handler specific to the namespaced class.

Thanks.

Comment: Just checked the docs. again and have worked out that this can be done with model observers, so use Person->observe(new PersonObserver) and pass the observer into the model.    That solves the problem, but would still like to know if the above is possible?

Comment: i think you listen to certain events like 'component.action' that gets called within your code with `Event::fire('component.action', [...])`. haven't used it yet tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eloquent for saving your models to the database you might want to try:

```
Event::updated('yourcontroller@yourmethod');
```

I use this method and it's simple, clean and works great!

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#model-events